# Working with jQuery UI Draggable, Droppable and Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an `ul` of draggable items `(#doc-editor-options ul li)`, an area for dropping those items `(#doc-editor-content)` and an `ul` within that area for holding those items `(#items-holder)`, which is sortable. This dragging and dropping is only one-way, only items from the list can be dragged and dropped into the holder.

```
$("#doc-editor-options ul li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '#item-holder',
    containment: $(".doc-editor")
});
$("#doc-editor-content").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui){
        console.log('dropped');
    }
});
$("#item-holder").sortable({
    placeholder: 'placeholder-highlight',
    cursor: 'pointer',
});
```

Two questions that I have:

1. Right now when I drag an item from the list and drop it into the other list, the `drop` callback for `.droppable()` is called twice. I think this has something to do with the `#item-holder` being sortable. I want it to only be fired when I drop an item into the list and only know about that item's `event` and `ui` in the callback.
2. I also need the functionality where by default, the `items-holder` is not sortable. The only time it becomes sortable is when you are dragging and hovering an item over it. So I can't sort the list by default, but if I drag an item over to it, I can choose where to place that item in the list (i.e. the list is now sortable) and once I drop it, the list becomes unsortable again.

**EDIT:** I figured out #2, I needed to bind `mousedown` to the draggable items which enables sorting then disables it on `mouseup`. Still having problems with #1, it seems like some of the `sortable` events are firing the `drop` callback when I drop an item in or I hover out of the item holder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 1:

Your drop() gets called twice because connectToSortable is also triggering a drop().

My suggestion would be to delete $("#doc-editor-content").droppable() altogether, and instead add the receive(e, ui) handler to your sortable.

## 2:

Your fix works. However I would suggest a much easier alternative: leave the sortable always enabled and add the option "handle: h2". (Pick any tag that will not exist within your LIs.) This will let you drop into the list, but disable user sorting in-place.

Example:

```
$('#item-holder').sortable({
  placeholder: 'placeholder-highlight',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  handle: 'h2',
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    console.log('dropped');
  }
});
```